# css no longer responsive after changed with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a website that has responsive css using media queries.

There is a div, called "map"

For width 500px and above there is the map inside the container

```
//html stucture
//header, menu

<div id="conteiner">
   //texts , images, forms, etc
   <div id="map"></div>
   <input type="button" id="showpage"...
   <input type="button" id="showmap"...
</div>

//footer

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
//other divs style here
#map {width:100%; text-align:center; position:relative; padding-left:0.1%; padding-right:0.1%; padding-bottom:60%;}
#showpage #showmap {display:none;}
}
```

For width 500px and below, map goes "fullscreen" by simply setting everything `display:none` except the map and the showpage button.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
//other divs style here, set to display none
#map {width:100%; heigth:100%; text-align:center; position:relative; margin:0; padding:0;}
#showpage {display:block; position: absolute;}// floats over map
#showmap {display : none;}
}
```

So far, OK, if I resize the browser I see the map go fullscreen, and back inside the container div when the browser's width is over 500 or not. So everything is responsive.

**The problem :**

When the map is fullscreen, (browser below 500px) I use the showmap/showpage buttons so the user can switch from the fullscreen map to the page and back to the map.

Showmap button is visible when the user sees the page, and can click it to see the fullscreen map again.

The buttons use javascript to set/unset `style.display:none` for the divs.

If the user clicks the buttons the css is **no longer responsive**. If i click the showpage button to "turn off" fullscreen map, I see the page. Then I resize the browser to get bigger, but the map never re-appears inside the container div

I guess when the javascript changes the css, the changes are permanent

How do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: When you update element "style" objects, those settings override the CSS. Rather than directly modifying the "style" object, you can add/remove CSS classes. That way, your CSS is still in control.

Comment: @Pointy. Quick response and interesting solution. Can you provide an example/link? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Instead of directly hiding elements by affecting the "style" in the DOM, you can add/remove a class.

In your CSS (somewhere; probably before the media query stuff):

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

Then in your JavaScript code:

```
function whatever() {
  // ...
  var theDiv = document.getElementById("something");
  if (time_to_hide( theDiv )) {
    theDiv.className += " hidden";
  }
  else {
    theDiv.className = theDiv.className.replace(/\bhidden\b/g, "");
  }
  // ...
}
```

Now you can leverage normal CSS rules for how different rules override each other.  If your "hidden" rule is towards the top of the CSS file, then anything in the media queries will override it. (In this case it probably doesn't matter, because you just want "hidden" to mean that the element isn't shown.)

Because you don't change the style in the DOM, when the "hidden" class is not present then the old rules apply exactly as they would have before the class was added.

Comment: So, clicking the buttons calls the `whatever` function? And `something` is a div? What do you mean by "your hidden rule" ? So sorry, but this is still kind of unclear for me

Comment: Yes; sorry that was supposed to be just an example. The idea is that instead of manipulating `yourDomEement.style.display`, you add or remove a class name from the "className" property. Then you use a CSS rule to mean that elements with that class name should be `display: none`. Exactly how that works into your code depends on the way your page works. (The "hidden" rule is the CSS rule for the "hidden" class; the one that starts with the ".hidden" selector.)

Comment: @slevin - just thinking; if you've got rules for the "display" css property in your media queries, you probably want that ".hidden" rule to go *after*, not before.  You may run into issues with CSS specificity rules; if so just ask another question and I'll keep an eye out for it :)

Comment: OK, I got the idea. Test it, for a simple div and works. I put the rule in the end of CSS file. Final question. If map is fullscreen and the browser get bigger, how can map return to its original size and fit its container instead of being fullscreen? Thanks again

Comment: @slevin well that's when you'd *remove* the "hidden" class. In my example I did it with `.replace()` and a regular expression. If you're using a library like jQuery or something there are easier ways to do it.

Comment: I think I made a div re-appear inside its container when the browser goes bigger. I put the "hidden rule" inside the media queries. Inside the media query for screen 500px and below. So, browser if its bigger, there is no "hidden" class, and div re-appears small and inside the container. This is a test for a div, but I think will also work for map. I 'll test for map and let you know...

Comment: For some reason it does not work when I try to implement it on  my page. I do what you said, try to set/unset classes and make `display:none/block` for the map and the other divs.Nothing works. No errors in the console, but does not work. I dont get it. What am I missing?